# Silverlight : WCF getting error on server but localhost works fine

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, iis-7

I have silverlight application and i'm getting this error :

```
[Async_ExceptionOccurred]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.61118.00&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred INNER >System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: [CrossDomainError]
Arguments: http://localhost/pthaba/SimpleWCF.svc
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.61118.00&File=System.ServiceModel.dll&Key=CrossDomainError ---> System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: [Arg_SecurityException]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.61118.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_SecurityException
```

I have an WCF service and works fine on browser.
I have clientacesspolicy.xml like below on root site (where is located the WCF service)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from >
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>

  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Can anybody helpme?

**EDIT :**

On my localhost works fine, but on server doesn't.
Fiddler seems ok, no error on that.

am i missing some IIS configuration?

More error details above :

```
 at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at Pthaba.SimpleSVC.SimpleWCFClient.SimpleWCFClientChannel.EndGetGameLevelPlataforms(IAsyncResult result)
   at Pthaba.SimpleSVC.SimpleWCFClient.Pthaba.SimpleSVC.ISimpleWCF.EndGetGameLevelPlataforms(IAsyncResult result)
   at Pthaba.SimpleSVC.SimpleWCFClient.OnEndGetGameLevelPlataforms(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
ult)
```

Comment: where is your policy file located ?

Comment: I often use fiddler to inspect this kind of problems. You should see the request to ClientacessPolicy.xml if the path is correct, etc. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Hi,
policy file is located on root suck like my service.svc

Comment: Just to be sure, your service is inside "pthaba" but the ClientacessPolicy must be on the root, not where the svc file is. It should be on the same folder where the pthaba folder is.

Comment: already changed the path but still with same error.

all requests on fiddler seems ok

Comment: Hi Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and got mine to work following this article: [Making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

I had to make one change as follows which someone commented on at the bottom of that article:

```
<allow-from http-request-headers="*">
```